# How to get output from stuffed `screen` command?

Tags: bash

I have a rust program that runs in the background on its own repl, meaning, it can accept commands at any time.  I needed a method of sending commands to it as a background process, so I chose to use `screen`.  When I send it a command with `screen -S accounts_hash -X stuff "total\n"` the output of this command, `total`, should be `0` which it is, but when I attempt to capture the output with `echo $(screen -S accounts_hash -X stuff "total\n")` it prints nothing.

**How could I capture the output of the targeted screen after sending it a command from outside the screen?**

or...
**Is there a better method for sending background processes commands?**  I've already tried redirecting to the location of the process `/proc/PID/fd/0` but the process would never seem to interpret the command; it would appear but would only pass through as if nothing had happened.

Comment: You need a way to communicate with the process itself. This isn't bash related per se. Essentially what you need is an api-endpoint that you call that sets the flag, and then that function has to have a callback to whereever your logic for the flag is stored. I guess u could run your program in a debugger and change flags on the fly. but u need to hook into the process itself then.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it belongs on another site; e.g. the Unix side.  See https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/12601

Comment: For what it is worth, you probably should not use "screen" for this at all.  Just run the "stuff ..." command inside the `$(...)`.

Comment: you can use my [sexpect](https://github.com/clarkwang/sexpect). it forks a program in background and you can talk with (send input and get output) the program in a programmable way.

Answer (score 0):

This is because you have not stored anything in the variable total. Also, I don't see where you declared the total variable in the bash script.